# linspace() generates a float values , but int is required

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am generating x-axis values which is time form 1 to 23 and v-values which is a number of clients. I want to join these 2 lists as dictionary which is done but I am getting float values of x as I generate using `linspace()`.

```
time_values = np.linspace(1,23,23) # print from 1,2...23
number_of_clients = [] # create empty list that will hold number of clients
        for i in range(1,24,1):
            rand_value =  random.randint(1,20) # generate number of clients
            number_of_clients.append(rand_value)


    data = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))
    print data
```

output is

{1.0: 12, 2.0: 11, 3.0: 3, 4.0: 19, 5.0: 12, 6.0: 12, 7.0: 5, 8.0: 13, 9.0: 15, 10.0: 3, 11.0: 15, 12.0: 20, 13.0: 5, 14.0: 3, 15.0: 18, 16.0: 12, 17.0: 5, 18.0: 6, 19.0: 8, 20.0: 16, 21.0: 19, 22.0: 1, 23.0: 16}

how to convert 1.0 to 1 and so on.I have tried `int(time_vlaues)`, but it did not worked

Answer (score 3):

try astype method to convert numpy float array to int array:

```
time_values = np.linspace(1,23,23) # print from 1,2...23
number_of_clients = [] # create empty list that will hold number of clients
for i in range(1,24,1):
    rand_value =  random.randint(1,20) # generate number of clients
    number_of_clients.append(rand_value)


data = dict(zip(time_values.astype(int),number_of_clients))
print(data)
```

or

```
time_values = np.linspace(1,23,23,dtype='int') # print from 1,2...23
number_of_clients = [] # create empty list that will hold number of clients
for i in range(1,24,1):
    rand_value =  random.randint(1,20) # generate number of clients
    number_of_clients.append(rand_value)


data = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))
print(data)
```

output:

```
{1: 17, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 3, 5: 12, 6: 11, 7: 18, 8: 1, 9: 8, 10: 1, 11: 17, 12: 2, 13: 5, 14: 6, 15: 1, 16: 8, 17: 19, 18: 2, 19: 13, 20: 15, 21: 16, 22: 17, 23: 14}
```